# Character with different bit representation in different encoding

Tags: unicode, encoding

I want a character which has different bit representation in different encoding. Like there could be some character whose codepoint is U+00AA. utf-8 should be representing it as 0x00 0xaa, but some other encoding say iso-latin-5 should be representing it as 0x01 0xab. I am learning about unicode and encoding and so want any such character to play around with it.

Comment: Don't focus too much on encodings, most of Unicode processing is about code point sequences independent of the encoding. Eg. the difference between graphemes and code points.

Comment: U+00AA in UTF-8 is `0xC2 0xAA`, and in Latin-5 is `0xAA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at UTF-7 *every* code point is encoded with a different octet sequence to UTF-8.